# How to redirect from an xhr request

Tags: node.js, redirect, xmlhttprequest, hapi.js

When I send an xhr post request to my server. It replies with a 302 redirect, but I can only log the entire redirect html, and cannot get the browser to redirect to the new url.

server.js

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Inert = require('inert');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
const port = 8888;

server.connection({ port });

server.register([ Inert ], () => {
  server.route([
    {
      method: 'get',
      path: '/',
      handler: (request, reply) => {
        reply.file('index.html');
      }
    },
    {
      method: 'get',
      path: '/login',
      handler: (request, reply) => {
        reply.file('login.html');
      }
    },
    {
      method: 'post',
      path: '/login',
      handler: (request, reply) => {
        reply.redirect('/');
      }
    }
  ]);

  server.start(() => {
    console.log('Server running on ', server.info.uri);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Home </h1>
    <a href="/login"> go to login </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="home">home</button>
    <script>
      function goHome () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('Response: ', xhr.response);
          }
        }
        xhr.open('post', '/login');
        xhr.send();
      }
      document.getElementById('home').addEventListener('click', goHome);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to redirect to '/' without doing it client side?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to redirect to '/' without doing it client side?

No.

A redirect means "What you asked for can be found here" not "Navigate the browser to this URL". The browser will only navigate to the redirected URL if it was going to navigate to the URL it originally asked for.

A request initiated by XMLHttpRequest will get a response that will be processed by XMLHttpRequest. If that response is a redirect, it will be followed and the response to the new request will be handled by XMLHttpRequest.

Ajax is the act of making an HTTP request from JS without leaving the page.

If you want to leave the page, don't use Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for something similar, ended up setting header and then on client side used that for redirect:

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', selector, (e, data, status, xhr) =>
  redirectToPath = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location')
  window.location = redirectToPath if redirectToPath
```

Can't give Node.js example, but basic Ruby on Rails controller method example with setting just `header` and `head` response:

```
def create
  response.headers['Location'] = polymorphic_path(@document, action: :edit)
  head(:ok)
end
```