# Redirect user after validating their ID token (GAE/Firebase)

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, web-applications, xmlhttprequest, firebase-authentication

I followed the diagram below to integrate Firebase Authentication to my GAE web app, but I am having trouble redirecting users to homepage after they log in.

[image]

Currently, I have a FirebaseUI widget on my login page that handles the authorization. I configured the widget such that it sends the ID token of the user to my backend server with an XHR as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) upon a successful login, so that I can verify the integrity and authenticity of the token. However, after I am done verifying, I am not able to redirect the user to homepage since apparently [that's how XHR works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273182/how-to-redirect-from-an-xhr-request/40284676#40284676).

As can be seen from my network logs below, my app does indeed request a redirection, but my browser does not respond to it.

[image]

I am not sure what the best way to proceed is as my experience in web development is nonexistent and Firebase documentation was not helpful. Any direction you can provide me would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this using a callback function that is executed on the frontend upon verification of the token. Something along the lines of:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/login',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'idtoken=' + idToken,
    success: function(response) {
        window.location.replace(response.redirect);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Handle error
    }
});
```